# Allowed memory size greater than required but throwing fatal error

Tags: php, memory, file-get-contents

I am trying to use `file_get_contents` on a file but get the error below:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 187260544 bytes) in /dir/public_html/dir/file.php on line
>   18

Unless I am mistaken the allowed maximum is greater than what I am trying to use so why the error? Is there another setting that needs to be taken into account?

Comment: You will need to show your code

Comment: My code is just:file_get_contents(path to file)

Comment: It means it exhausted the allowed memory and tried to allocate additional. How big is the file? Its the obvious thing

Comment: The allowed memory size is for everything php does for the request. Perhaps by the time you try to load the file you've already used up enough memory to cause this problem? What's on lines 1 - 17 of file.php? Are there any other php files included? Is this within the context of a framework or just a single php script? We need more information and/or more code shown.

Answer (score 0):

The total memory used by your code cannot exceed your maximum memory allowed. If you call `memory_get_usage` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) just before you do `file_get_contents` you'll probably find that the amount there + the 187260544 btyes for the file you want to load exceed the maximum allowed of 187260544 btyes.

If so then you have other variables in memory using up a lot of memory. If you're loading other files into memory, consider clearing them (if you can) before loading this one (using `unset`) or consider streaming the file instead by reading it line by line using `fgets` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) or using PHP streams (http://php.net/stream).